# How to debug an ARM process which is running inside QEMU (with a gdb-server) under linux (remotely) but using the windows host?

Tags: visual-studio-code, arm, remote-debugging, qemu, gdbserver

I would like to attach to a remote gdb-server which is running under linux. Actually it is an ARM process which is running in a QEMU under a linux host.
And I use Visual studio code for the debugging under windows.
Is it generally possible to do so?

I have setup the visual studio code under another linux machine and try to connect to the remote gdb-server and it works well.
But the visual studio code under windows doesn't work.

I think conceptually it should be possible to debug this process. Because it is an ARM process but it is just running under QEMU under linux and if I have the corresponding toolchain in window, then it should be no different, right?

Then the question might be which tool-chain is needed to be installed under windows (under linux I installed aarch64-linux-gnu)?

In the visual studio code, I need to specify the gdb tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the toolchain here:

https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/

And if I use the similar toolchain but for windows host, then it works well and I can attach to the process with no problem from the windows host.